# Soft Keyboard keep closing when click of editText of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a fragment which contents a ViewPager2 of 2 fragemnts.
In the second child fragment, I have a recyclerview which viewholder contains TextView and EditText.

In emulator, when I click in EditView, the soft keyboard keep closing.

In real device (Sony xperia XA), the soft keyboard not closing but it always focus on the first edit text whether I click in another EditText

I have tried to use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" and android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" but it don't fix the problem.

I use DataBinding and ConstraintLayout outside LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="vn.com.ntn.obee.screens.fragments.exercise.InputQuestionFragment">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/question_drawable"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <vn.com.ntn.obee.screens.views.SelectableTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvQuestion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.6"
                android:maxHeight="200dp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
                app:htmlText="@{answer.content ?? answerResult.contentExtend}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etAnswer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/size_icon_x5"
                android:hint="@string/enter_your_answer_here"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_input_question_edittext"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova_bold"
                android:textColor="@color/pink"
                android:textColorHint="#FFC9C9"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvQuestion"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I think these log may have I find the problem:

```
2020-10-12 00:20:43.527 3051-3051/? I/KeyboardViewUtil: KeyboardViewUtil.getKeyboardHeightRatio():128 systemKeyboardHeightRatio:1.000000; userKeyboardHeightRatio:1.000000.
2020-10-12 00:20:43.528 3051-3051/? I/AndroidIME: AbstractIme.onActivate():83 LatinIme.onActivate() : EditorInfo = Package = com.nghianguyen.obee_android.debug : Type = Text : Learning = Enable : Suggestion = Show : AutoCorrection = Enable : Microphone = Show : NoPersonalizedLearning = Disable, IncognitoMode = false
2020-10-12 00:20:43.529 3051-3051/? I/Delight5Facilitator: Delight5Facilitator.initializeForIme():572 initializeForIme() : Locale = [en_US], layout = qwerty
2020-10-12 00:20:43.529 3051-3051/? I/VoiceInputManagerWrapper: VoiceInputManagerWrapper.cancelShutdown():54 cancelShutdown()
2020-10-12 00:20:43.529 3051-3051/? I/VoiceInputManagerWrapper: VoiceInputManagerWrapper.syncLanguagePacks():66 syncLanguagePacks()
2020-10-12 00:20:43.557 3051-6376/? I/SpeechFactory: SpeechRecognitionFactory.maybeScheduleAutoPackDownloadForFallback():155 maybeScheduleAutoPackDownloadForFallback()
2020-10-12 00:20:43.569 1845-1845/? E/servicemanager: Could not find android.hardware.power.IPower/default in the VINTF manifest.
2020-10-12 00:20:43.596 3051-3051/? I/KeyboardWrapper: KeyboardWrapper.consumeEvent():264 Skip consuming an event as current keyboard is deactivated (state=0, keyboard existence=true)
2020-10-12 00:20:43.669 3051-3051/? W/KeyboardModeManager: KeyboardModeManager.setInputView():359 setInputView() : inputView = com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.framework.core.InputView{cb5f35e V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2022}
2020-10-12 00:20:43.672 3051-3051/? I/ConversationToQueryExtension: ConversationToQueryExtension.isEnabledForHostApp():254 Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.nghianguyen.obee_android.debug] not in whitelist
2020-10-12 00:20:43.672 3051-3051/? I/ConversationToQueryExtension: ConversationToQueryExtension.onActivate():165 onActivate() : Disabled by unsupported host app
```

Comment: can you share item's xml layout?

Comment: @NehaK I have updated item's xml layout into the question

Comment: can you post code of "vn.com.ntn.obee.screens.views.SelectableTextView"

Comment: for me its working fine, but haven't tried with SelectableTextView, issue could be inside this only

Comment: @NehaK I have try to delete SelectableTextView but It is not the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is I use too much constraint layout.
I use constraint layout for:

- The ViewPager's Child Fragment.
- The item of recycler view.

I changed my layout to LinearLayout for the fragment & FrameLayout for item have solve my problem.

Note: Using NestedScrollView to wrap my recycler view dose solve my problem but it prevent I scroll the recycler view

Comment: Hi @KhoaChau I'm also using viewPager2 and one of the fragment is contain RecyclerView, and item on RecyclerView contain EditText.
The keyboard is keep closing when EditText is clicked

So from your solution -> means all item recyclerView cannot using ConstraintLayout?